# How To Break Content Security Policy?

Tags: javascript, html, security, http-headers, content-security-policy

Content Security Policy seems really robust, but I don't think it's perfect (and I've seen sources that refer to it as a "partial" prevention for XSS). My question is: what sorts of XSS attacks does it not prevent?

Answer (score 2):

No all browsers have implemented it, so users using non-supported browsers it offers no protection.

http://caniuse.com/#search=csp

Even on supported browsers, unless the Content Security Policy is to disable all JavaScript (in-line, internal/external domain) then it still leaves areas open to where JavaScript can be run.  Which means, if any malicious JavaScript can make its way into those zones, then Content Security Policy will not stop the XSS from happening.

Some examples of of where CSP will not stop XSS:

- If an application is using inline (on the page) JavaScript and the CSP policy allows it.  If unencoded/unvalidated/malicious values are put into the page then the browser will run the malicious JavaScript just like it will run the intented JavaScript.  (Currently ASP.Net Web Form apps need JavaScript to run on the page, so any malicious input that is displayed will be executed by the browser.
- If you are dynamically creating your JS files for your app and unencoded/unvalidated/malicious values are inserted into that file, that will cause a XSS vulnerability.
- If you are sending pages and/or JavaScript files over http and not https an a MITM attack can modify the values over the wire.
- If you are loading JavaScript files from a third party domain and their security gets compromised, malicious scripts could be sent to your app instead of the originally intended scripts (think CDNs).

These are just some of the examples I could think of off the top of my head.

Some of these concerns look like they can be mitigated through use of the CSP Level 2 directives, but there is limited support for them.

In short, CSP is a very nice layer of defense, but it should not be your only line of defense.  Even though it will not cover everything and not all browsers currently supported it, it is an additional layer of security I can use to keep my application and users safe.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "if any malicious JS can make its way into these zones"? How might that happen?

Comment: Assuming you don't allow inline scripts or eval, a CDN (hosted jquery for example) compromise is one example. Subresource integrity can help mitigate that threat.

Comment: Good answer. I agree - I tend to think of CSP as a safety net. The real defence to XSS is proper output encoding, however a robust CSP can save your bacon should an output be missed out of the encoding routine, giving you chance to repair it before it can be exploited. Just one question - can you expand on what the CSP Level 2 directives are and how they will mitigate the risks?